# How to configure gvim for jumping to matching ifdef/endif

Tags: vim, matching

I'd like to configure gvim, so the '%' command will jump to the matching `` `ifdef `` / `` `endif `` (there is a back-tick before ifdef and endif) the same way it works for #ifdef/#endif.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: See `:help matchit-install`.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up with copying the plug-in, and modifying it. Didn't find a way to customize thru .vimrc